# Python in Beautiful Soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to fetch text between

```
<label>A</label> class A <br/><label>B</label> class B <br/> <label>C </label> class C <br />
```

Expected output in Dictionary like data

```
{'A':'class A','B':'class B','C':'class C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `<label>` tag and then get next text sibling to it.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<label>A</label> class A <br/><label>B</label> class B <br/> <label>C </label> class C <br />'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

data = {label.get_text(strip=True): label.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip() for label in soup.select('label')}
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'A': 'class A', 'B': 'class B', 'C': 'class C'}
```